# How do I get the bot to post Spoiler Images in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py

I started with discord.py a month or two ago, so this might just be really simple.
My code is:

```
    attachment_url = ctx.message.attachments[0].url
    await archiver.send(attachment_url)
```

"archiver" is the channel I'm sending it in.
How do I make it send with a spoiler tag?  I looked through the docs but they're not helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order for you to upload an image as a spoiler, you need to add `SPOILER_` to the start of the image name, you can do that with:

```py
file = ctx.message.attachments[0]
file.filename = f"SPOILER_{file.filename}"
spoiler = await file.to_file()
await archiver.send(file=spoiler)
```

Comment: Thank you! This really helped