# Is there a way to mark an Image link as a spoiler - Discord bot

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Im very new to coding and i want to make a bot that sends an image link, marked as a spoiler.

I got this from [a different stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60408884/how-do-i-get-the-bot-to-post-spoiler-images-in-discord-py/60409739#60409739)

```
file = ctx.message.attachments[0]
file.filename = f"SPOILER_{file.filename}"
spoiler = await file.to_file()
await ctx.send(file=spoiler)
```

The problem is i have no idea where to put the image link!

(If you're wondering why i didn't ask in a comment on [that post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60408884/how-do-i-get-the-bot-to-post-spoiler-images-in-discord-py/60409739#60409739), its because i don't have enough rep)

Comment: Isn't it the same as marking regular text as spoiler?

Comment: I tried that, if you mark the link with the "||" it just turns the link into a spoiler, and does not embed the image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer, if you add || around the link like this ||url|| it just wont embed. But if you add a space like this || url || than it will be marked as a spoiler.