# Trying to spoiler an image send via link acquired by praw module (discord.py)

Tags: discord, discord.py

```
@commands.command()
    async def fifty(self, ctx):
        _5050 = reddit.subreddit('FiftyFifty').hot()
        post_to_pick = random.randint(1, 10)
        for i in range(0, post_to_pick):
            submission = next(x for x in _5050 if not x.stickied)
        
        await ctx.send(submission.url)
```

The submission.url sends an image using a link, How do I spoiler the particular image?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60408884/how-do-i-get-the-bot-to-post-spoiler-images-in-discord-py) help?

Answer (score 0):

Since you’re sending an URL, you can simply put it in between double pipes - `||`

```py
await ctx.send(f"||{submission.url}||")
```