# DISCORD.PY - Bot bot sends image as spoiler

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm trying to get my bot to send an image as a spoiler, but I'm not having success. The image comes from a URL, but how do I mark it as a spoiler?

my code:

```
@client.command()
async def ordema(archiver): #command
    await archiver.send(f'https://imageproxy.ifunny.co/crop:x-20,resize:640x,quality:90x75/images/a475315bd258dc83078c79ea338a0118919944fbecdc8b1bb5d4bda5d3dbab53_1.jpg') #image url
```

Comment: I believe discord supports SPOILER_img.png

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get the bot to post Spoiler Images in discord.py?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60408884/how-do-i-get-the-bot-to-post-spoiler-images-in-discord-py)

Answer (score -1):

As said in my comment:

Discord supports the addition of `SPOILER_` to images. Your code could look something like this:

```py
file = ctx.message.attachments[0]
file.filename = f"SPOILER_{file.filename}"
spoiler = await file.to_file()
await archiver.send(file=spoiler)
```

Comment: This don't work. Where I put my link? Can you explain this code to me?

Comment: @JefersonJunior Get the image, and then just add SPOILER_ to the front.

Comment: But I don't want to download the image, I want the bot to send the image from the link as a spoiler. I already put 'SPOILER_' in front of the link and I was not successful.

Comment: You have to download the image to add spoiler. That is the only way, you can delete it after if you are minimising storage usage.

Comment: Don't work again :// thats my code:

@client.command()
async def ordemc(archiver): #command
    file = archiver.message.attachments[0]
    file.filename = f"SPOILER_DrEstranhoPutaria.jpg"
    spoiler = await file.to_file()
    await archiver.send(file=spoiler)

Comment: Can u help me? I'm can't do it

Comment: @JefersonJunior SO is not a spoonfeeding service, I have gave you the right direction.